# How to convert string to Date in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, casting

I have defined my update query as follows to update a **Date** column.

```
declare @fromDate date;
set @fromDate = '2019-04-31'

update [dbo].[sites] 
  set [FromDate]= @fromDate 
where siteid=2832
```

Above gives following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character 
>       string.

What Im doing wrong here?

Comment: That is teh catch thanks alot..im trying for an hour with this silly issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

April doesn't have 31 days, if you pass invalid date you will get error. Try with some valid date like 2019-04-30

Answer (score 0):

If it will work is most likely dependent on what settings you run on your server for dates. You can use `CONVERT(datetime, '2019-04-31')` this will convert any string to datetime type that your server supports.

Comment: When I do above conversion I get  this error.//The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.//

Comment: @Ratha . . . If this isn't the problem, then the most likely issue is a trigger on the table.  Have you looked at the triggers?